# Should I use get or post? Or both?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, client-server

I’m relatively new to get and post etc, so any help is welcome!

In my App.js file, I have a user text input field and a submit button, and I’d like to do a couple things with this information:

1. Return a string from my server.js file to the same page
2. Increase a counter each time the button is pressed and output this value to a separate stats.js file

Am I on the right lines by thinking I should use a **post** to send the button click event back to server.js, and another post to return the string from server.js?

And the same for the second point?

I.e. In the button onClick function:

```
<form action = '/' method = ‘POST’>
```

And in the server.js, something like:

```
App.post('/', (req, res) {
    // return string code here
}
```

I think I just need a bit of guidance on which files i should be doing methods :) any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<FORM>` actions should always be a `POST`

As a general rule for other transfers - use `GET` to 'request' data, and `POST` to send/upload it.

Comment: "actions should always be a POST" — This is entirely wrong. There is a reason that forms have a `method` attribute. There are lots of times GET is the correct option. A search engine's search form for example.

Answer (score -1):

Read [section 4 of RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4).

Forget about the user interface for the moment.

You want to get some information from the server and record some statistics about it.

The statistics are a side effect, they aren't the real purpose of the request, they are essentially just a standard *access.log* file. This means that, despite the record of the request being made, you are making a *safe* request.

So make **one** request, and make it a GET request.